# Windows removing reliance on old boot-able disk

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

- The system is windows 10.
- Windows 10 was installed on a standard hard disk.
- Got a new SSD and then installed a clean windows 10 installation on that.  It works fine - all good so far.
- As I installed Windows 10 more than once my system gave me the option to boot into whichever, but now that I've set up the new installation I no longer require the old one.
- Opened up 'System Configuration' and removed the other bootable options.  Great - now when I start up I don't have to pick something or wait for the default option.
- Decided to remove the old hard disk, but the system wouldn't boot from the SSD. The bios has the SSD listed as boot-able, so why would it not work?
- When I added back the old hard disk and the system started up again fine, but I do not wish to rely on the old hard disk. The old hard disk must contain some bootable information, but I'm not sure how or what to remove and then what will need to be added to the new SSD.

Comment: You need to create an EFI partition on the SSD then rebuild the boot configuration data.  You can accomplish that several ways.  The simplest method uses the tools within WinRE to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesnt work is that the boot sector was on the original drive.  Even though BIOS has the drive marked as bootable, that simply means BIOS will look for the boot sector on the drive.  Since its not there, it will fail to boot.

Repairing/rewriting the boot sector is very easy.  Here are some easy [instructions](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/) to follow.

Comment: Great, I'll try that later and report back. Would have thought that when installing new OS onto disk it would have created the means to boot of the same drive.